# Razor Token ResetPassword Not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, security, razor

I have an MVC3 Razor web site.  I am following the tutorial here:

http://www.thecodingguys.net/tutorials/asp/webpages-membership-forgot-password-and-reset-password

I have been able to generate a token and send the email successfully

Then the email has me going to a resetpassword view at a link like this:

~/Account/resetpassword?token=fujgFIo7k27c72-UTTJeGA2fujgFIo7k27c72-UTTJeGA2

Now, here is my HttpGet method

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult resetpassword()
    {
        ResetPasswordModel model = new ResetPasswordModel()
        {
            Password = String.Empty,
            ConfirmPassword = String.Empty,
            Token = String.Empty
        };
        return View(model);
    }
```

All it does is pass in an instance of the model

My view for resetpassword.cshtml

```
@model RazorARPP.Models.ResetPasswordModel
@{    
    var token = Request["token"];
    Model.Token = token;
}



<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="MyForm">
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<fieldset>
<legend>Reset Password</legend>
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Token)
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
@Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)
@Html.ValidationMessage("password")

<br/>

@Html.LabelFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword)
@Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword)
@Html.ValidationMessage("confirmPassword")

<input type="submit"/>

</fieldset>
</form>
```

Now My HttpPost method

```
[AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult resetpassword(ResetPasswordModel model)
    {
        if (model.Password == model.ConfirmPassword)
        {
            WebSecurity.ResetPassword(model.Token, model.Password);
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Login");
    }
```

It executes fine but the resetpassword isn't working.  I made sure that that line is running in the debugger.  Any suggestions as to what I am doing wrong?  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you generating the reset token? Are you using the correct username?

```
WebSecurity.GeneratePasswordResetToken(model.Email)
```

Do a test where you generate a token and immediately pass it to `WebSecurity.ResetPassword`. I'm guessing `resetpassword` is not getting the values you are expecting

Comment: currently I am doing 
var token = WebSecurity.GeneratePasswordResetToken(model.UserName, 1440);

Then sending an email to the user.  I also see the token in the database has changed to the one that is getting sent (PasswordVerificationToken)

Comment: @Badmiral Do a quick test, make it simple. Remove the expiration time, put GeneratePasswordResetToken and ResetPassword back to back. Make sure you can reset a password this way. Then add the email, then set the expiration time.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with the email when it sends the token it is duplicated.

```
 var confirmationUrl = hostUrl + VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/Account/resetpassword?token=" + token +  HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(token));
```

Should be like this

```
 var confirmationUrl = hostUrl + VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/Account/resetpassword?token=" +  HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(token));
```

There all should work now!

Look at your own URL

~/Account/resetpassword?token=fujgFIo7k27c72-UTTJeGA2fujgFIo7k27c72-UTTJeGA2

the token is duplicated, that was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This call will fail (return false) if the password entered doesn't fulfill the password rules. Check what settings you have in your config file for your membership provider.

Also depending on the membership provider it may return false if the account is locked - but I can't verify that right now.